# Get the value of a specific record in dicts with lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I have a dict like this:

```
contactos = dict([
    "id", id,
    "nombres", nombres,
    "apellidos", apellidos,
    "telefonos", telefonos,
    "correos", correos
])
```

And it works when I put a new register in every *key:value*, my problem is, how can I get the record for only one contact?
I have a part where I can input a number and search the position in the list of the dict, then I want to only show the record of that specific record in every *key:value*

I made this code, but it doesn´t work.

```
telefo = input(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "TELEFONO CONTACTO: " + Fore.RESET)
    for x in range(len(telefonos)):
        if(telefonos[x] == telefo):
            print(contactos["telefonos"][x])
        else:
            print("No encontrado")
```

I print only the telefono value, ´cause it´s my test code.

Comment: in what the code doesn't work, could you give us a output example?

Comment: I think you want a database.  Make a "contactos" table where the columns are your keys ("id", "nombres", etc) and each row is a new contact.  That way you can search for contacts based on any field.  For example, `SELECT * FROM contactos WHERE telefonos = [insert number here]`. Python has libraries for working with databases.  I use `MySQLdb`.

Comment: BTW, The dict you have in your question is not valid python.  Is it supposed to be a dict where the value of each key-value pair is a list?

Comment: Now i got another error, i change the structure of the dicct, and yes, is a dict where i have the name for the key, and the value for each key is a list, but know i got TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your working script:

```
# I imagine your data to be somethig like this. If it isn't, sorry:
id = 0
nombres = ['John', 'Anna', 'Robert']
apellidos = ['J.', 'A.', 'Rob.']
telefonos = ['333-444', '222-111', '555-888']
correos = ['john@email.com', 'anna@email.com', 'rob@email.com']

# This is the part where you made it wrong.
# Dictionaries are created with {}
#
# [] creates a list, not a dictionary structure.
#
# Also, key and values must be grouped as:
# "key": value
contactos = dict({
    "id": id,
    "nombres": nombres,
    "apellidos": apellidos,
    "telefonos": telefonos,
    "correos": correos
})

# Now, imagine this this is the input from user:
telefo = "333-444"
for x in range(len(telefonos)):
    if (telefonos[x] == telefo):
        print(contactos["telefonos"][x])
        break
    else:
        print("No encontrado")
```

When testing the script, the output is `333-444`.

Comment: That´s exactly what i was looking for! Now i understand better my mistake, thanks for the help